# Intellij Java Methods not being used within if else method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to design a cash card that has holds money in cents and points. So when you spend 2000 cents, you'll earn 2000 points (1:1 ratio) which are automatically redeemed as a 10 cent cash back. You need to have at least 2000 points in the card to redeem cash back. You can only use the card if there's enough money to cover the entire purchase before any cash back is added. The problem I'm having is that the points aren't being deducted from the points balance of the card and cash back isn't being provided. I was wondering if there's anywhere in my code that I messed up. thanks

```
public static int POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK = 2000;    // points needed to get cash-back reward
public static int REWARD_POINTS_PER_CENT_CHARGED = 1;    // points earned for each cent charged to card
public static int CASH_BACK_REWARD = 10;                 // reward in cents


private int NUMBER_OF_CASH_BACKS;
private int POINTS_ON_CARD;
private int initialBalance; //must be integer larger or equal to 0

public boolean makePurchase(int amount) {


    if (amount < initialBalance) {
        initialBalance = (initialBalance - amount);
        POINTS_ON_CARD = (POINTS_ON_CARD + (amount * REWARD_POINTS_PER_CENT_CHARGED));

        if (POINTS_ON_CARD > POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK) {
            NUMBER_OF_CASH_BACKS = POINTS_ON_CARD / POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK;
            POINTS_ON_CARD -= (NUMBER_OF_CASH_BACKS * POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK);
            initialBalance += (NUMBER_OF_CASH_BACKS * CASH_BACK_REWARD);
        }

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

and here's my test that I ran, it's not complete as I was trying to figure out a way to return the new points value.

public void testPurchase3()

{
        //When the cash balance on the card is sufficient and there is enough points for cash back

```
    int oldBalance = testCard.getBalance();
    int oldPOINTS_ON_CARD = testCard.getRewardPoints();

    testCard.makePurchase(2000);

    assertEquals(oldBalance - 2000 , testCard.getBalance());

    assertEquals(testCard.getRewardPoints() ,
            oldPOINTS_ON_CARD + (2000 * FoodServicesCard.REWARD_POINTS_PER_CENT_CHARGED));

    assertTrue(testCard.getRewardPoints() >= FoodServicesCard.POINTS_NEEDED_FOR_CASH_BACK);
```

Comment: Could you include what values the variables hold?

Comment: If what is inside the if{} not running, then most likely, the if statement isn't being satisfied. Try putting a simple System.out.println("check 1 ok"); at the beginning of the if{} to see if the text is being printed.

Comment: if (amount < initialBalance)

Looks more like a boundary condition, so if the amount = 2000 and the initialBalance = 2000 then it will not hold true